# Why is $-4a^3c + a^2b^2 + 18abc - 4b^3 - 27c^2$ the discriminant of an elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, discriminant

We have an elliptic curve in its normal form:

$$y^2 = f(x) = x^3 +a x^2 + bx + c,$$
where $a,b,c$ are rational numbers. The discriminant [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653368/discriminant-of-elliptic-curves) is said to be

$$-16(4b^3 + 27c^2) \quad \text{ or } \quad 4b^3 + 27c^2.$$

However, in *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* (Silverman & Tate) it is defined as

$$-4a^3c + a^2b^2 + 18abc - 4b^3 - 27c^2.$$

It looks like the first is of the same form only when $a = 0$, so the second form is more general. My question is: where on earth is this derived from? There is no such derivation given in the book.

Comment: Try computing the Jacobian and seeing which values of $(a,b,c)$ causes the curve to be singular.

Comment: The linked question is talking about a different form though? It was talking about $y^2 = x^3 + \color{red}{ax + b}$.

Comment: Hmm, sorry. I don't know what the Jacobian of an elliptic curve is.

Comment: @VTand, well yes. But the point is the $x^2$ term has coefficient $0$ in the first case, regardless of how you notate it.

Comment: You can always reduce the form to kill off the quadratic term, so the discriminant is usually given in that form. If one applies that transformation (and its inverse), I imagine it moves between the statements of the discriminant. In any case, the discriminant you gave is just the general discriminant for a cubic (with constant term one). Just look up discriminant on Wikipedia and see how to calculate it... It's just a bit of linear algebra.

Comment: Well sometimes isn’t quite difficult to remove the quadratic term? I was hoping someone could show how to derive it in normal form and not Weirestrass form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the cubic
$$ x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c, $$
replace $x$ with $X-\frac13 a$ to get
$$ X^3 + BX + C = X^3 + (b-a^2/3)X + (c-ab/3+2a^3/27).$$
Now compute $4B^3 + 27C^2$ to get
$$ 4b^3 + 27c^2 + 4a^3c - a^2b^2 - 18abc. $$